# Are all the Unicode characters supported on Android

Tags: android, unicode, character, android-softkeyboard

My question is simple. Are all Unicode characters available in Android?
I actually am using the soft keyboard and I want to add a few arabic letters which I can't find the codes for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android supports UTF-8 but you will not be able to use arabic, if it's not installed in your OS. There are ways to install new fonts, but some of them  needs jailbreaking your phone.

See link for installing font in Android:

https://web.archive.org/web/20091023103506/http://www.android-devs.com/?p=33

Answer (score 3):

It does not appear so.  [This open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=507) on the android code site lists many missing characters.

Answer (score 2):

add font (.ttf) containing characters to /system/fonts, modify /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml so android finds font then reboot. Everything should be working now

Comment: To make the answer more complete, you could also tell if this solution requires jailbreaking the mobile phone.