# stop xml entity from producing square

Tags: android, xml, entity

i have the following in my xml file and it gives me a square ⃠

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<Button android:text="&#8416" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
...
```

the character is the "no symbol"/prohibited   symbol but it shows up like a square...other symbols show up fine like euro €.

question is how do i get the symbol to show up and if i cant, how can i know what symbols will and wont work....is there a master list somewhere

Comment: Ok is that no entry sign symbol? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%26%238416%3B&lk=1

Comment: its usually called  the "no symbol" or the "prohibited symbol" but whats depicted in the link is correct

Comment: ok see my answer - using the image that way it guarantees the output to the user's screen is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so due to various reasons it won't show up and [there are other posts on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766912/are-all-the-unicode-characters-supported-on-android).

Why not use a left drawable in the image by:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/myicon"
```

Same result and you don't have to worry about character encoding and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on the Font you are using. I had a link to look that up. I'll get back here as soon as I find it.

Update:
Here you go - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/index.htm